# Position noise sources on blank map?

Tags: geolocation, maps, geocoding, geospatial

I am going to describe the experiment. I have a big field, huge field. In that field there are trees, bushes and multiple speakers (5). Those speakers don't move and emit a unique sound.

I also have a mobile device that captures every sound. It is able to differentiate each speaker and ignore the white noises. The device gives the speakers a value for how loud the sound is. Every second, the device saves a list of the speakers and how loud their sound is. When I move near to a speaker, the device finds the sound louder.

At the end of the experiment, I have a table with the speakers' loudness over time. This should be enough to triangulate each point.

Would Pythagoras do the trick? (earth isn't perfectly flat)
Does anyone have a mathematical formula or library?
Does anyone know how I could trace a map with that information?

Thanks you

Answer (score 1):

Fun question.

You will need to be able to map changes in loudness to positions. To do that you'll need to know the falloff rate. This will vary depending on frequency - low and high fall off at different rates. This is not Pythagoras.

That will give you a range of positions in a circle around the speaker.

Repeat this for two speakers and you'll have two overlapping circles. Their intersection will be a single point. That will be the location. That location is the point with the right angle in the right triangle.

You now know where you are relative to the speakers, but not where you are in the world.  But you'll know the position of each speaker in advance. You can add their x,y coordinates to your relative coordinates to get the absolute position.

(Actually these shapes are 3D, so the circles will be spheres and the x,y coordinates will be x,y,z coordinates).

At this stage you can use Pythagoras to get the distance between the two speakers. But you will already know where you are on the field by this stage, and you'll have found it out without using Pythagoras.